# Php script run next to windows clock

Tags: php, windows, toolbar

Hello i have a php script that return some values from mysql database
I want those results to shown on windows toolbar next to windows clock for example in a fieldset or something

Any ideas?
thanks a lot

Comment: this is not a job for php, you want something like c to create an executable application

Comment: make a c program to echo a php script? something like that?

Comment: No. Write your whole program in C. However, Python would be much easier for you.

Comment: i know php and i have already manage it now, the only think i want is to show the results in windows toolbar

Comment: @Pcdoctorvirus Please share your solution, I'm curious

Comment: dagon i havent upload it on server, i still work it localhost

Comment: php on your server has no control of a clients machine, it runs on the server

Comment: php is the wrong tool. 5 minute job with .net language.

Comment: so show me david those 5 minutes

Answer (score 3):

PHP won't really do this (unless you use GTK, something I wouldn't recommend).

What I would suggest is that you use php to create a basic web api. Then you'd need to use .NET, Java, C++, etc to build a desktop application to consume that api and display the application near the clock.

Comment: you think its easy to include php result through .net?

Comment: It's fairly easy. You can easily make a http request in .net in a few lines of code.

Comment: ben rowe can u help in that?i cant find something on web

Answer (score 0):

Growl might be of help:

http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/

Growl is a notification system - originally born on Mac OS X - which allows clients to post notifications. Maybe one of the Growl plugins does what you want.